# Cannot enable 'Gnome Shortcuts' plugin in Audacious music player!

Tags: gnome, shortcuts, plugins, audacious, checkbox

I am using Audacious as my default music player and I want to control my play list with Fn keys. I have checked some FAQ that say: "check (enable) the 'Gnome shortcut' plugin under 'Audacious> File> Settings> Plugins> General' but the matter is here! I can check and un-check (enable and disable) all of plugins there but cannot on 'Gnome shortcut' plugins!!!
Do anyone have the same problem?
How can I enable it anyway!?

Comment: See this: https://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/765

Comment: Oh, thanks for the comment! I used a tricky way instead of that. ( enabling shortcut key plugin and set new control shortcuts with <ctrl> key and It works.) Also a new version of Audacious-music player release few days ago but again I can't able to turn that plugin on.) sorry about late respond. Good luck.